# Submitting time from Javascript to Python Backend

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, timezone

I have a form which sends a date object from javascript to python backend. The date is entered in `GMT +0530`, but in python, it gets parsed into `GMT +0000`.

The following are the javascript logs:

```
> $scope.my_date.getTime()
< 1480617000000
> $scope.my_date
< Fri Dec 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

So, the above date gets parsed into `Thur Dec 01 2016 18:30:00 GMT+0000`.

How can I send the time-zone of the country where the form was filled so that I can use that timezone to convert the time from `Dec 01` to `Dec 02`?

I can send the offset in hours (to the python) by the following method:

```
> $scope.my_date.getTimezoneOffset()/60
< -5.5
```

But, Python's [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) understand's timezone in `"Asia/Kolkata"` format, not the `-5.5` format.

I can adjust the date with `-5.5` manually, but I'm looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following method to get around the above problem.

I changed the time in the JS itself before sending it to the server.

```
($scope.my_date.getTime()/1000) - ($scope.my_date.getTimezoneOffset()*60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit with `Math.floor($scope.my_date.getTime()/1000)`, and on the python side just read the unix timestamp.

To explain: `getTime()` returns a unix time stamp with milliseconds, or the number of miliseconds since:

> 1 January 1970 00:00:00 **UTC**

I've bolded the last bit because it's important. It doesn't matter what timezone you're in when you create a unix time stamp, it's always UTC. Every programming language and tool that deals with unix time stamps properly will read in the time stamp as UTC, and convert internally into the local/correct timezone.

So don't complicate things with trying to parse date strings - just use the time stamp - it's universal.

The only gotcha is the conversion (the `/1000` with a `Math.floor`) to remove the milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't understand the question. I get that the time is in UTC. I want to pass the timezone information along with unix timestamp to the server.